# How to best re-allocate interfaces to move to a different VDC

Tags: cisco-nexus-7k

I'm working on re-allocating interfaces that are on a N7K-M132XP-12L (32 port 10 Gig module) in a Nexus 7k.

The ports are currently configured as follows

```
vdc router_VDC_2 id 2
allocate interface Ethernet1/1-24 
vdc router_VDC_3 id 3
allocate interface Ethernet1/25-32
```

I need to move 8 interfaces from VDC_2 to VDC_1. The 8 I would like to move is 1/16-24.

How do I go about moving the interfaces without causing any kind of outage on VDC 2?

Would the following work?

```
vdc router_VDC_1 id 1
allocate interface Ethernet1/16-24
```

Comment: PS ports 16-24 are actually 9 interfaces, 17-24 are 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that these ports are just access ports and are not participating in any routing or VLAN trunking which would cause a STP re-convergence or a routing re-convergence. It should be safe to move them.

You should not have to specify the id field.
This command should simply work:

```
vdc router_VDC_1
allocate interface Ethernet1/16-24
!now exit, switchto vdc and begin configuring the interfaces
switchto vdc router_VDC_1
int e1/16
  no shut
  ....etc
```

The only outage you'll see when moving ports between VDCs is on the ports themselves.
By default - the config they are populated with on the new VDC is simply shutdown. So the devices attached will have their links drop until you configure and unshut the interface.

**Update:** I didn't notice that you mentioned that since this is a N7K-M132XP-12L card - the port assignments work in 4's due the way the ASICS are configured. You would not be allowed to move port 16. If you did, it would cause ports 11, 12, & 13 to move with it. You could move e1/17-24 without any problems.